# Data transfer between computer and Fieldfox N9917A using Python VXI-11 library

Tags: python, spectrum-analyzer

I accessed my Fieldfox device using the vx-11 library. But now I don't know which commands to access the data with. For example, with the CALC:FEED:MODE AVER command? I use Fieldfox programming guides for this. Is there a ready-made code example for these comments? For example, I want to know the power level of the peak signal. I want to print this value to the excel file. Am I right for this, can I do this with this library?
[image]